# Is it possible to create table and schema using pg-promise nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

> Am trying to bulk import using the below code in node js but before that, I need to create a table.

```
  const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['incdt_crte_by_i', 
        'incdt_asgn_to_i'], {table: 'incdt'});

  // data input values:
 const values = [{incdt_crte_by_i: 'a1', incdt_asgn_to_i: 'b1'}, 
 {incdt_crte_by_i: 'a2', incdt_asgn_to_i: 'b2'}];
```

Comment: Of course it is possible. Was there a problem doing it? What have you tried? - show the code. P.S. The helpers namespace methods got nothing to do with that. You create tables by executing the corresponding CREATE TABLE script, etc.

Comment: thanks @vitaly-t , it worked

Comment: Do you have any solution to merge two tables